# Secure Web Chat in C# ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net, algorithm, encryption, web, chat

First, I'm working on a Master student's project, the project is a Web Bank System and apply encryption algorithms on this system.

The first algorithm which is a new encryption algorithm designed by the student who requested my help is to encrypt the sensitive data (Credit Cards information) on the database.

The second algorithm (which is a modified AES algorithm) is to encrypt the messages between the customer of the bank and the admin of the bank system using a web chat room.

Of course, there is no problem with the first algorithm because I can apply it to encrypt the Credit Card information submitted by the user and save it on the database.

But, the problem is that the professor that supervising on this student project insisted to secure the messages sent across the network by the admin and customer that they are using the web chat room and these messages must be secured using the second algorithm (modified AES).

As you all know, if I just code the second algorithm in Javascript to encrypt the messages on the browser client machine then send those encrypted messages to the server, that means this algorithm will be available to anyone who opens this webpage because we all know that Javascript is an open client source.

So, no more talking, I just want to ask that:

How to apply any encryption algorithm to secure the data transfer between client machine and server machine by using web application (for example web chat application) without to be this algorithm an open source to any client machine?

Comment: use HTTPS to secure the _entire connection_ between the browser and the server. Just like every other secure website the world over. There's no point, as you rightly say, to try and encrypt the individual data items, or to write any kind of encryption code in the JavaScript.

Comment: I agree with you ADyson, but the professor insisted to use this algorithm to secure the connection, as well as, keep this algorithm secret from anyone else.

Comment: I doubt it was meant to cover the connection between browser and server. Unless of course your professor doesn't understand web technology. Perhaps you should clarify this point with them.

Comment: I clarified the whole situation to him, but he insists to find the solution. I told him if we would just design a windows forms application for this matter, but, he refused. He still insists to bring him a solution to encrypt the message by our own way in web chat technique

Comment: I can only suggest maybe that you do it and then produce a demo of how to crack it, in case he doesn't get it. Sorry you're in a situation with someone who doesn't seem to really know the tech they're asking you to work with. I suppose there's a tiny chance he knows some new thing that we don't. But then I'd expect more of a clue. P.s. AFAIK SSL certificates used for HTTPs don't use AES because it's symmetric, so I don't think it's a trick question, but you could maybe quickly research that.

Comment: I totally agree with your, and believe me, I already know all that. The only thing to ask this question is just to make sure that I'm right about my thoughts. I will explain to my professor this whole discussion and I make my best to clarify that this is almost impossible to achieve that.
Thanks to you all guys

Comment: By all means give him a link to this question. I'm even happy to have a chat discussion with him about this issue if he wants to open a stackoverflow account! Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

ADyson's comment contains the best solution to solve this problem practically, but it sounds like the professor has added constraints that prevent you from employing a practical solution.

It is not possible to execute an encryption algorithm on a client machine and at the same time keep the encryption algorithm a secret from the person and machine running the algorithm.  They can always inspect the code.

Comment: I have an idea and I would like to take your advise. If I code the algorithm in Java and make this chat room as a Java applet application to be used by the browser, could be this the solution?

Comment: If I understand the situation correctly, then the Java application will be running in the user's browser.  No, this solution will have no security advantages over running javascript in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware this is not possible, because the client will have to be able to both encrypt and decrypt messages; it logically requires the client understanding the encryption algorithm.

The strength of an encryption mechanism comes from the difficulty of reversing an encrypted message to plaintext without the key, even if one knows the algorithm.

If knowing an encryption algorithm allows someone to decipher a message without the key, then the algorithm is weak.

Comment: The algorithm used is AES but it's has been modified to be stronger.
The problem is that this algorithm uses a symteric key which the key used in encryption is used to for decryption as well.
Is there any hope?

Comment: The key should be generated per session, and possibly even multiple times per session.

Other forms of encryption would be employed to encrypt the initial transfer of the new key.

HTTPS would be the way to go if making a production system - but you would actually need two forms of encryption to do so on your own.

Comment: I have an idea and I would like to take your advise. If I code the algorithm in Java and make this chat room as a Java applet application to be used by the browser, could be this the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, that leaves the same problem - you would have to use HTTPS or another means to encrypt the connection in order to transfer the Java applet.  If a man in the middle listening can intercept the applet containing the key, then they can use the key to decrypt future connections.  We would refer to this as obfuscation; it may be a bit trickier, but you would simply be hiding it, instead of encrypting it.  The trick is to utilize an asymetric encryption handshake to establish an encrypted tunnel, that would temporarily be used to transfer the key your modified AES algorithm will use.